# Converting numbers to formatted strings and parse the formatted string again

Tags: c++, winapi, localization, globalization

In visual c++ I need to format the numbers according to the current thread locale using the number format of the windows, like using digit grouping separators and decimal point of windows, also parsing it again like C#.NET.

```
convert double b = 108457000.89 to "108,457,000.89"
also convert "108,457,000.89" to double b = 108457000.89
```

this article was so useful in converting the number to a formatted string http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14952/A-simple-class-for-converting-numbers-into-a-strin

but how to reverse the operation that wasn't clear i want to know how to do it??

Comment: Storing these kind of numbers in a *double* is almost never not a mistake.  Monetary values should be stored in a data type that uses base-10 encoding, like C#'s System.Decimal.  Not supported in the C++ standard, you'll need to go shopping.  Otherwise supported in MSVC++ with the COleCurrency class, note the ParseCurrency() method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that really didn't help i used it to parse 234,098.6700 and it treated it as 234.0000 , it can't understand the digit grouping symbol. I found this article also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9600/Windows-SetThreadLocale-and-CRT-setlocale I didn't read it till now if I found any solution in it I will mention it in here

Answer (score 2):

You might do it like this (and ignore that article):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    // Environment
    std::cout << "Global Locale: " << std::locale().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "System Locale: " << std::locale("").name() << std::endl;

    // Set the global locale (To ensure it is English in this example,
    // it is not "")
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_GB.utf8"));
    std::cout << "Global Locale: " << std::locale().name() << std::endl;

    // Conversion string to double
    std::istringstream s("108,457,000.89");
    double d = 0;
    s >> d;
    // Conversion double to string
    std::cout << std::fixed << d << std::endl;
    // This stream (initialized before main) has the "C" locale,
    // set it to the current global:
    std::locale c = std::cout.imbue(std::locale());
    std::cout << "Locale changed from " << c.name()
        << " to " << std::cout.getloc().name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::fixed << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note:

- Run it in a terminal/console (My develop environment Eclipse has the
  C locale)
- You might have to adjust the "en_GB.utf8"

Result:

```
Global Locale: C
System Locale: en_US.UTF-8
Global Locale: en_GB.utf8
108457000.890000
Locale changed from C to en_GB.utf8
108,457,000.890000
```

A Warning:

```
Libraries may rely on the global local being the "C" local.
```

Comment: This is so nice, I have looked at it but my problem is how to get the locale name for the current thread??? that was a great challenge, I'm targeting a client PC and I don't know what it the locale settings english or german or arabic,.....

Comment: @Ahmed safan: Means the above code does not work in a thread !?

Comment: It works but as you wrote 'You might have to adjust the "en_GB.utf8"' and I want it to be the same as the thread locale this method get the current thread locale as an ID but not a name http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318127(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Ahmedsafan: You noticed, the system locale is equivalent to "" ? (sorry I made an edit, there)

Comment: I noticed it but it is the system locale whatever the current user input, I want to get the currently user input culture. I have arabic egypt and english us , when i select one culture how to retrieve that.